# How to increase Google Sheets v4 API quota limitations

Tags: google-sheets-api

The new Google Sheets API v4 currently has an unlimited read/write quota per day (which is fantastic), but restricted to 500 reads/writes per account per 100 seconds, and 100 read/writes per key per 100 seconds (or, I have found, multiple keys coming from the same IP).  This is probably plenty for most use cases, but I have an edge case that requires bringing a frequently-updated Google Sheet with 70 tabs down to a node.js server that distributes these to user's clients every ~30-60 seconds or so (users are data annotators who are student research assistants).  This wasn't so bad early in the project when there were only 20-30 tabs, but now that the data is large the server is blowing through the 100 quota and returning errors every 10-15 minutes.

The problem is such that:

1. Frequent data updates: Only data on 1-5 of the 70 tabs is likely to be updated on any given minute, but which tabs have new data is random (so I am pulling down the whole sheet of 70 = 70 reads).
2. Update interval: The need for updates happens randomly at about 30 second to 5-minute intervals (so some within the quota, some about 3-5x the quota).
3. Throttling: I have tried throttling the update to be within the 100 calls/100 seconds (my previous solution), but this introduces large usability issues, significantly decreasing usability/productivity/work quality.
4. Quota increase: The sheets API does not currently appear to include a way to pay to increase the quota.  It does allow filling out a form to request an increase in the quota, but I'm not sure what the mean response time is on this (my request is only a few days old).
5. Multiple service accounts: I have tried using multiple service accounts to get the full 500 requests/100 seconds quota (rather than the per-user quota), since this is a server, but Google Sheets looks to rate-limit to 100 requests/100 seconds from a given IP
6. Alternatives: I have considered that this project may have just grown beyond the size that Sheets is easily able to handle, but there do not appear to be any good, usable, self-hosted, collaborative spreadsheets with easy-to-interface-to APIs out there.

Are there settings/methods suggested to achieve the full 500 calls/100 seconds for a server?

Answer (score 11):

1. You can use [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to read the entire spreadsheet in a single call, rather than 1 call per request.  Alternately, you can use [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) to read multiple different ranges in a single call, if all you need are the values.

   - Similarly for update requests, instead of doing individual updates with `spreadsheets.values.update`, we can use `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` across multiple cell ranges even across different sheets.
2. The Drive API offers "[push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push)", so you can get notified when changes occur and react to those, instead of polling for them.  The latency of the notifications is a little on the slow side, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't realize that batchGet could accept multiple ranges across different tabs/worksheets, and I've replaced my get calls with batchGet to reduce retrieving the 70 tabs from API calls into 2 API calls (one to list which tabs/worksheets are available for a given sheet, the second to batchGet to retrieve all the rows in each tab).  These two links were helpful: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet    https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading (very bottom)

Comment: Do you happen to know what spreadsheets.get actually does? Can you emulate the request without the library?

Answer (score 11):

You can request quota update in Google Cloud Platform and it will be increased to 2500 per account an 500 per user. (about your #4)
[image]

Comment: Do I need to create a Billing account for this? Could you elaborate on the procedure?

Comment: No, it's free.  Go to https://console.cloud.google.com => API and Services => Quotas => Edit any "Read requests per" => Send request and send Google Sheets API Quota Request

Comment: @Alex Great! The link seems to have moved to > IAM & admin > Quotas (not sure if it's the same as you mean?).

Comment: @Alex For me, requests over the defaults require an "apply for higher quota" form to be filled, first. (Filled, now proceeding to create multiple service accounts as a plan B).

Comment: @Alex The quota request doesn't seem to allow more than 500 request per 100 seconds for an account without billing account. Can you please check it?

Comment: Hi...does it mean that currently you have to have a paid standard support account costing 29usd per month?! That sounds insane just to increase API resquest...cause currently i get the message: You don't have permission to file tech-related support cases