# Are the quotas for reads and writes separate, or shared?

Tags: google-sheets-api

There are conflicting information about this.

This [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225734/how-to-increase-google-sheets-v4-api-quota-limitations) indicates the reads/writes share a quota, but in the Google Cloud Console > IAM & admin > [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page they are presented separately, with no indication of sharing the quota.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sheets API Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) states that they are tracked separately:

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per
>   100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.
>   **Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately**. There is no daily usage limit.